# If any function \kappa is given, is there always exist a function which its curvature function is \kappa?

Tags: differential-geometry, curves, curvature

> Let $\kappa 2 : (a,b) \subset \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R} $ be a arbitrary function.
>
> Then is there always exist a function satisfies
>
> $ {f''(x) \over (1+(f'(x))^2)^{3/2}} = \kappa 2(x)  $  ?

I thought about a function

$ \kappa 2(x) =  \begin{cases}
 & 1 \text{ if } x \in \mathbb{Q} (\subset (a,b))  \\ 
 & 0 \text{ if } x \notin \mathbb{Q} (\subset (a,b)) 
\end{cases}$

But I couldn't find the way to prove that there is no function satisfies above conditon.

Answer (score 1):

As $f''$ exists, $f'$ is continuous. $f''$ is a derivative and [derivatives have the Darboux property](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Darboux%27s_theorem_(analysis)). Prove that the LHS has the Darboux property and you have a contradiction.